# Alternative to Collectors.groupingBy() for scala

Tags: java, scala, collectors

In Java I have something like:

```
Collectors.groupingBy((Re r) -> return r.pName)
```

And it works properly. Now I'm trying to get the same thing into scala, like:

```
Collectors.groupingBy((r:Re) => return r.pName)
```

but then I get stuff like

```
cannot resolve reference groupingBy with such signature
cannot resolve symbol groupingBy

unspecified value parameters Collector
unspecified value parameters Supplier
```

Let me know if you need any more info/code, and I'll create some dummy example since I'm not allowed to post the exact code.

**Update** based on @Vladimir Matveev answer:

pName should be String, but if I write `new java.util.function.Function[Re, java.lang.String]` then I get a

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[Re,String]
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: Re, _ <: ?0(in value x$1)(in value x$1)(in value x$1)(in value x$1)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java lambdas are "implementors" of arbitrary functional interfaces (in this particular case `Collectors.groupingBy()` accepts `java.util.function.Function`. Scala anonymous functions, however, are instances of some class implementing `scala.FunctionX` trait. Consequently, you can't use Scala functions for arbitrary functional interfaces (but there are plans to allow that, as far as I know).

You need to create an anonymous class extending `java.util.function.Function` explicitly:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(new java.util.function.Function[Re, ???] {
  def apply(r: Re) = r.pName
})
```

(you need to put correct type of `pName` instead of `???`, of course).

If you're doing this often, you can define an implicit conversion for Scala's `T => U` to `java.util.function.Function[T, U]`:

```
implicit class FunctionWrapper[T, U](f: T => U) extends java.util.function.Function[T, U] {
  def apply(x: T): U = f(x)
}
```

Then (given that this implicit is in scope) you can use it like you tried initially:

```
Collectors.groupingBy((r: Re) => r.pName)
```

**Update** I have no idea why your error happens (probably because of some incompatibilities between Scala and Java generics), but if you specify all types explicitly it does work:

```
scala> Collectors.groupingBy[Re, String](new JFunction[Re, String] {
     |   def apply(r: Re) = r.pName
     | })
res2: java.util.stream.Collector[Re, _, java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[Re]]] = java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@4f83df68
```

(`JFunction` is an alias for `java.util.function.Function`).

The variant with an implicit adaptor looks nicer (but still requires explicit type annotations):

```
scala> Collectors.groupingBy[Re, String]((r: Re) => r.pName)
res4: java.util.stream.Collector[Re, _, java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[Re]]] = java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@71075444
```

Comment: found the issue, it needed [Re, java.lang.String] after groupingBy

Comment: i meant that your update was helpful, not that i found it by myself :D